# Run Time Error 424 Object Required

Tags: ms-access, vba

I been working on the following code to when the user click on the button to save and go new record that Access locates the highest client id used by set location and then adds 1 to it. Prior to saving the record and moving on to new record.  While work through other errors, but I can not get past error object required on this line.  "Me.ClientID = IIf(DMax("[ClientID]", "tClientinfo", "[CorpsName]=" & "'defaultcorps'") Is Null, 0, DMax("[ClientID]", "tClientinfo", "[CorpsName]=" & "'defaultcorps'")) + 1"

The more i look at the similar questions more confused I get as to what is wrong with the code.  Thank you in advance for any suggestions David

```
    Private Sub Save_Record_Click()

'declare variables for default values
Dim defaultinterviewr As String
Dim defaultcorps As String


'Variables get their values
defaultinterviewr = Me.Interviewer.Value
defaultcorps = Me.Corps.Value

'Check to see if ClientID field is Blank.
If IsNull(Me.ClientID) Then

'Check that Corps field is filled in

If IsNull(Me.Corps) Then
    MsgBox "Corps must be entered before saving record.", vbOKOnly
    Me.Corps.SetFocus
'set client id base on corps by finding the highest id and adding 1 to that number
Else
Me.ClientID = IIf(DMax("[ClientID]", "tClientinfo", "[CorpsName]=" & "'defaultcorps'") Is Null, 0, DMax("[ClientID]", "tClientinfo", "[CorpsName]=" & "'defaultcorps'")) + 1
End If
End If
MsgBox "Done", vbOKOnly

'save record
'DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
'Me.stateidnum1 = ""
'open new record
'DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

'set field default value
'Me.Interviewer.Value = defaultinterviewr
'Me.Corps.Value = defaultcorps

'Me.Child_Subform.Form.AllowAdditions = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start off by figuring out if your DMAX() statement is correctly producing results. The next thing I see and which is probably your main culprit is the fact that you are using the Expression IIf() inside VBA. The IIf() expression you are using will work inside a query or in a textbox but VBA has it's own If statement block which you are correctly using in the lines preceding it.

I would actually use the Nz Function to simplify it even more as follows:

**UPDATED** Based off of your comment below I re-looked at your overall code and noticed that "defaultcorps" is a variable and not a value I originally thought you were trying to filter by. You were wrapping the variable in quotes. My updated answer should work for you.

```
Me.ClientID = (Nz(DMax("[ClientID]", "tClientinfo", "[CorpsName]= '" & defaultcorps & "'"),0)+1)
```

Comment: Anthony Thank you pointing out the DMAX function is not working that is my promblem. Though I can not figure out the right syntax for field, table, and critera.

Comment: See my updated answer above. I missed the fact that defaultcorps was a variable and not a data value. This update should produce what you are looking for.

Comment: Glad I can help. You can mark it as the answer in case someone else has a similar question.